# unix - output manipulation using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file in my unix box where data is like below

```
Output-1
========
abc
x.sh
y.sh
mnk
qrs
a.sh
b.sh
mno
qwe
```

I want the output to be modified as below

```
Output-2
========
abc||x.sh
abc||y.sh
mnk
qrs||a.sh
qrs||b.sh
mno
qwe
```

Can we achieve it using awk?

Actually I have some text and I want to find the scripts where this text is found. I am able to achieve it but the Output-1, but I want it as Output-2 format. The code I am using is as below

```
#!/bin/ksh

input_file=$1
dir_list=$2

while read dir_list; do
  while read -r line; do
    echo $line; grep -i $line /code/${dir_list}/scripts/*.sh|awk -F":" '{print $1}'|uniq;
  done < ${input_file} > code_${dir_list}_scripts.txt
done < ${dir_list}
```

Comment: I have provided what I tried already

Comment: Can you describe the rules you need to follow to determine whether a line should be joined to the next or previous line? For example, any line starting with "a" or "q" should have the following two lines joined?  Or, lines whose numbers are a multiple of 4 are always on their own?

Comment: In my example "abc" is the search text and "x.sh" & "y.sh" are the script names. The output I am getting having search text first then followed by script names. But I want the result like search test then separator the script name. If there are multiple scripts then search text will also be repeated multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -v OFS='||' '/\.sh/{print p, $0; pp=0; next} 
                 pp    {print p} 
                       {p=$0; pp=1} 
                 END   {if(pp) print p}' file

abc||x.sh
abc||y.sh
mnk
qrs||a.sh
qrs||b.sh
mno
qwe
```

**Nomenclature:** `p` is to store previous keyword, `pp` is for the flag to print previous keyword.

Comment: The solution you provided is not 100% working. Means if I have 2 more keywords and for which I didn't find any script then the output is missing "qwe" from the above example.

Comment: I have added 2 more lines in Output-1 and Output-2 to explain this scenario.

Comment: added `END` block to handle missing keywords after last regex match.